# How do I turn this blue themed image into a red one? Gimp

Tags: gimp

Here is the image. How do i turn it into a red themed image?
Maybe white to gold and dark blue gradient to red??
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Colors` -> `Hue-Sauration...` then select `Master` and adjust the `Hue` slide to the right; e.g. give it +130.  Here is the result:

[image: here is the result]

Comment: What, no turning white into gold?  You're not an alchemist?  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm partial to `Color>Map>Rotate colors`. Unlike others, it maps a range of colors to another (you seldom have a pure hue....):

[image]